# Creating a new column based on a window and a condition in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

INITIAL DATA FRAME:

```
+------------------------------+----------+-------+
|          Timestamp           | Property | Value |
+------------------------------+----------+-------+
| 2019-09-01T01:36:57.000+0000 | X        |     N |
| 2019-09-01T01:37:39.000+0000 | A        |     3 |
| 2019-09-01T01:42:55.000+0000 | X        |     Y |
| 2019-09-01T01:53:44.000+0000 | A        |    17 |
| 2019-09-01T01:55:34.000+0000 | A        |     9 |
| 2019-09-01T01:57:32.000+0000 | X        |     N |
| 2019-09-01T02:59:40.000+0000 | A        |     2 |
| 2019-09-01T02:00:03.000+0000 | A        |    16 |
| 2019-09-01T02:01:40.000+0000 | X        |     Y |
| 2019-09-01T02:04:03.000+0000 | A        |    21 |
+------------------------------+----------+-------+
```

FINAL DATA FRAME:

```
+------------------------------+----------+-------+---+
|          Timestamp           | Property | Value | X |
+------------------------------+----------+-------+---+
| 2019-09-01T01:37:39.000+0000 | A        |     3 | N |
| 2019-09-01T01:53:44.000+0000 | A        |    17 | Y |
| 2019-09-01T01:55:34.000+0000 | A        |     9 | Y |
| 2019-09-01T02:00:03.000+0000 | A        |    16 | N |
| 2019-09-01T02:04:03.000+0000 | A        |    21 | Y |
| 2019-09-01T02:59:40.000+0000 | A        |     2 | Y |
+------------------------------+----------+-------+---+
```

Basically, I have a Timestamp, a Property, and a Value field. The Property could be either `A` or `X` and it has a value. I would like to have a new DataFrame with a fourth column named `X` based on the values of the `X` property.

1. I start going through the rows from the earliest to the oldest.
2. I encounter a row with the X-property, I store its value and I insert it into the X-column.
3. **IF I encounter an A-property row:** I insert the stored value from the previous step into the X-column.
4. **ELSE (meaning I encounter an X-property row):** I update the stored value (since it is more recent) and I insert the new stored value into the X column.
5. I keep doing so until I have gone through the whole dataframe.
6. I remove the rows with the X property to have the final dataframe showed above.

I am sure there is some sort of way to do so efficiently with the Window function.

Comment: Given TS 2:59:40, 2's X value should be Y in the expected output. Right?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a temp column with value X's value, null if A. Then use window to get last not-null  Temp value. Filter property "A" in the end.

```
scala> val df = Seq(
     |   ("2019-09-01T01:36:57.000+0000", "X", "N"),
     |   ("2019-09-01T01:37:39.000+0000", "A", "3"),
     |   ("2019-09-01T01:42:55.000+0000", "X", "Y"),
     |   ("2019-09-01T01:53:44.000+0000", "A", "17"),
     |   ("2019-09-01T01:55:34.000+0000", "A", "9"),
     |   ("2019-09-01T01:57:32.000+0000", "X", "N"),
     |   ("2019-09-01T02:59:40.000+0000", "A", "2"),
     |   ("2019-09-01T02:00:03.000+0000", "A", "16"),
     |   ("2019-09-01T02:01:40.000+0000", "X", "Y"),
     |   ("2019-09-01T02:04:03.000+0000", "A", "21")
     | ).toDF("Timestamp", "Property", "Value").withColumn("Temp", when($"Property" === "X", $"Value").otherwise(null))
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Timestamp: string, Property: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> df.show(false)
+----------------------------+--------+-----+----+
|Timestamp                   |Property|Value|Temp|
+----------------------------+--------+-----+----+
|2019-09-01T01:36:57.000+0000|X       |N    |N   |
|2019-09-01T01:37:39.000+0000|A       |3    |null|
|2019-09-01T01:42:55.000+0000|X       |Y    |Y   |
|2019-09-01T01:53:44.000+0000|A       |17   |null|
|2019-09-01T01:55:34.000+0000|A       |9    |null|
|2019-09-01T01:57:32.000+0000|X       |N    |N   |
|2019-09-01T02:59:40.000+0000|A       |2    |null|
|2019-09-01T02:00:03.000+0000|A       |16   |null|
|2019-09-01T02:01:40.000+0000|X       |Y    |Y   |
|2019-09-01T02:04:03.000+0000|A       |21   |null|
+----------------------------+--------+-----+----+


scala> val overColumns = Window.orderBy("TimeStamp").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

overColumns: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec@1b759662

scala> df.withColumn("X", last($"Temp",true).over(overColumns)).show(false)
+----------------------------+--------+-----+----+---+
|Timestamp                   |Property|Value|Temp|X  |
+----------------------------+--------+-----+----+---+
|2019-09-01T01:36:57.000+0000|X       |N    |N   |N  |
|2019-09-01T01:37:39.000+0000|A       |3    |null|N  |
|2019-09-01T01:42:55.000+0000|X       |Y    |Y   |Y  |
|2019-09-01T01:53:44.000+0000|A       |17   |null|Y  |
|2019-09-01T01:55:34.000+0000|A       |9    |null|Y  |
|2019-09-01T01:57:32.000+0000|X       |N    |N   |N  |
|2019-09-01T02:00:03.000+0000|A       |16   |null|N  |
|2019-09-01T02:01:40.000+0000|X       |Y    |Y   |Y  |
|2019-09-01T02:04:03.000+0000|A       |21   |null|Y  |
|2019-09-01T02:59:40.000+0000|A       |2    |null|Y  |
+----------------------------+--------+-----+----+---+

scala> df.withColumn("X", last($"Temp",true).over(overColumns)).filter($"Property" === "A").show(false)

+----------------------------+--------+-----+----+---+
|Timestamp                   |Property|Value|Temp|X  |
+----------------------------+--------+-----+----+---+
|2019-09-01T01:37:39.000+0000|A       |3    |null|N  |
|2019-09-01T01:53:44.000+0000|A       |17   |null|Y  |
|2019-09-01T01:55:34.000+0000|A       |9    |null|Y  |
|2019-09-01T02:00:03.000+0000|A       |16   |null|N  |
|2019-09-01T02:04:03.000+0000|A       |21   |null|Y  |
|2019-09-01T02:59:40.000+0000|A       |2    |null|Y  |
+----------------------------+--------+-----+----+---+
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I asked. What if in the Initial Dataframe I have one more categorical field called "device_ID" and I would like to have a final dataframe like the one you managed to generate, but in respect of each device. In other words, doing the same but for each value of `device_ID` separately. This means that the time stamp order matters only for the rows with the same `device_ID`. And of course, a specific `device_id` has both A and X properties.

Comment: `Window.partitionBy("device_id").orderBy("TimeStamp").rowsBet....`  you partition by "device_id" like that

Comment: Wow, so easy/immediate! I did not know about this `partitionBy` function. Do you think should edit the question with this other sub-issue and request to edit your answer as well? I think it might be useful for other users..